# Unable to extend partition into adjacent unalloacted space

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I have recently used dd_rescue to recover a 2tb partition from a failing hard disk onto a new 4tb disk. That means the partition has ~2tb of unallocated space adjacent to it on the disk. I would like to expand this partition to occupy the entire 4tb of the disk, but I am not able to do so.

In Windows the option is greyed out and in Partition Wizard I am told there is not enough free space.

I have two questions:

1. Can anyone explain why this is happening, since i don't have a very good understanding of the underlying mechanics of disk partitioning?
2. Can anyone suggest how I might solve this? Note that formatting the disk is not an option given that the only other copy of the data is on a disk that is in the process of failing. I have access to a linux machine if there is some linux tool better suited to the job.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only in GPT you can use the entire 4TB hard disk. The MBR can only support up to a 2TB disk. Beyond the 2TB, the space could be invalid. Even if it shows as unallocated space at the end of the disk, you cannot partition it. Check whether your motherboard is UEFI compatible.

Thus, converting an MBR disk to a GPT disk is an effective way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its the limitation of MBR filesystem that you can not create a partition as it only supports partitions that are upto 2TB. You also can't create more than 4 Primary partition in MBR filesystem.

To overcome this difficulty, you'll have to change the Partition table of that Hard Disk.

You can do this using the Windows Disk manager or even with MiniTool Partition Wizard. 
Just Right Click the Disk and select the option of change into GPT or something like that.

Be aware that it will erase all your data on the hard drive.

Comment: LOL yes. Corrected it. :)

Comment: I managed to do the conversion in Partition Wizard without deleting any data from the disk.